# How to return a generic Map struct?

Tags: closures, rust

I'm not sure how return a generic `Map` struct now that the declaration for `Map` has changed. The new declaration is:

```
pub struct Map<A, B, I: Iterator<A>, F: FnMut<(A,), B>> {
    // some fields omitted
}
```

I'm not sure how to return one of these from a function:

```
fn something<A: Clone, I: Iterator<A>>(iter: I) -> Map<A, (A,A), I, **what goes here**> {
    iter.map(|x| (x.clone(), x))
}
```

I've tried using the signature of the closure I'm using...

```
fn something<A: Clone, I: Iterator<A>>(iter: I) -> Map<A, (A,A), I, |A| -> (A,A)> {
    iter.map(|x| (x.clone(), x))
}
```

But then rust complains that I need an explicit lifetime bound. I'm not sure why I need this, but I add it anyway:

```
fn something<'a, A: Clone, I: Iterator<A>>(iter: I) -> Map<A, (A,A), I, |A|:'a -> (A,A)> {
    iter.map(|x| (x.clone(), x))
}
```

But then I get the error: `the trait core::ops::Fn<(A,), (A, A)> is not implemented for the type 'a |A|:'a -> (A, A)`

I haven't been able to progress any further, and at this point I'm just trying random things. Can someone help me understand how to use the new `Map` struct?

Comment: Were you able to return a Map struct before this recent change?

Comment: Yeah, `fn something<'a, A, I: Iterator<A>>(input: I) -> Map<'a, A, (A, A), I>` worked fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't put anything meaningful in `**what goes here**`. The closure you define has a compiler-generated type that you can't name (that is, until [abstract return types](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/518) are implemented).

Since your closure doesn't capture anything from its environment, you can replace it with a normal function.

```
use std::iter::Map;

fn duplicate<T: Clone>(a: T) -> (T, T) {
    (a.clone(), a)
}

fn something<A: Clone, I: Iterator<A>>(iter: I) -> Map<A, (A,A), I, fn(A) -> (A, A)> {
    iter.map(duplicate as fn(A) -> (A, A)) // cast required since PR #19891
}
```

However, if you *do* need to capture some state, the best you can do (without resorting to boxing) for the moment is to define your own type that implements `FnMut`. (This example has an empty struct because there's no state; `call_mut` could access and alter the struct's state through `self`.)

```
#![feature(unboxed_closures)]

use std::iter::Map;

struct Duplicate;

impl<T: Clone> FnMut(T) -> (T, T) for Duplicate {
    extern "rust-call" fn call_mut(&mut self, (a,): (T,)) -> (T, T) {
        (a.clone(), a)
    }
}

fn something<A: Clone, I: Iterator<A>>(iter: I) -> Map<A, (A,A), I, Duplicate> {
    iter.map(Duplicate)
}
```

Comment: And if I did want to use boxing, would it look something like @Shepmaster's solution? What are the runtime costs of using boxed closures over defining our own struct like this?

Comment: Boxing requires a heap allocation, which is relatively costly, especially if you call the function repeatedly. My solution has no cost, especially considering the struct has no state, and therefore it has a size of zero (i.e. it doesn't even require any memory on the stack!). But yes, if you want to go with boxing, Shepmaster's solution is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Here's *a* solution...

```
#![feature(unboxed_closures)]

use std::iter::Map;
use std::slice::Items;

// Box<Fn> should probably work "out-of-the-box", but I couldn't get it to...
struct Z<'a, Args, Result>(Box<Fn<Args, Result> + 'a>);

// So let's define it ourselves!
impl <'a, Args, Result> std::ops::Fn<Args, Result> for Z<'a, Args, Result> {
    extern "rust-call" fn call(&self, args: Args) -> Result {
        self.0.call(args)
    }
}

fn do_it(a: &[int]) -> Map<&int, int, Items<int>, Z<(&int,), int>> {
    // Needed to specify the parameter type, too
    a.iter().map(Z(box |&: x: &int| *x + 1))
}

fn main() {
    let a = vec!(1 , 2 , 3);
    let b = do_it(a.as_slice());
    let c: Vec<_> = b.collect();
    println!("{}" , c)
}
```

My working hypothesis is that you cannot return a `Fn` (or friend) directly, because it is unboxed. Unboxed closures aren't sized, so the calling function doesn't know how much space to reserve for it.

To work around that, we need to return something that *does* have a size: a `Box`! Surprisingly (and I'd hope temporarily), `Box<Fn>` doesn't itself implement `Fn`, so I created a wrapper struct that I could implement it myself.

I'd expect that in the future, you'd be able to just return a box and dispense with the wrapper struct, but I went ahead and tried to make it generic enough to suffice for now.

Comment: Yes, this seems similar to the `ClosureEnvironment` example in http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2014/11/26/purging-proc/. One question: what's the `extern "rust-call"` for?

Comment: I'm not very sure, I just copied it from other uses in the Rust code. Based on [some](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/0669a432a2e09ad08886cb2138dbe9f5d681fb7f/src/librustc_trans/trans/base.rs#L1612) [comments](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/0669a432a2e09ad08886cb2138dbe9f5d681fb7f/src/librustc_trans/trans/base.rs#L1677) in the [compiler](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/0669a432a2e09ad08886cb2138dbe9f5d681fb7f/src/librustc_trans/trans/base.rs#L1850) it looks like a method call where all the args are packed into a single tuple.