# How do I return a Filter iterator from a function?

Tags: generics, iterator, rust

I want something like that:

```
fn filter_one<'a, T: Int>(input: &'a Vec<T>) -> ??? {
    input.iter().filter(|&x| x == Int::one())
}
```

What's the return type of that function? (I want to return the Iterator)

(I hope this isn't too obvious, I've been trying for half an hour now and am just starting to get frustrated :p )

**EDIT:**

I tried to follow the instructions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27535289/correct-way-to-return-an-iterator) => [playpen link](http://is.gd/SZK4mM)

the compiler gives me the following error:

```
<anon>:5:1: 7:2 error: the trait `core::kinds::Sized` is not implemented for the type `for<'r> core::ops::Fn(&'r T) -> bool + 'a`
<anon>:5 fn filter_one<'a, T: Int>(input: &'a Vec<T>) -> Filter<&T, Iter<'a, T>, Fn(&T) -> bool>{
<anon>:6     input.iter().filter(|&x| x == Int::one())
<anon>:7 }
<anon>:5:1: 7:2 note: required by `core::iter::Filter`
<anon>:5 fn filter_one<'a, T: Int>(input: &'a Vec<T>) -> Filter<&T, Iter<'a, T>, Fn(&T) -> bool>{
<anon>:6     input.iter().filter(|&x| x == Int::one())
<anon>:7 }
<anon>:5:1: 7:2 error: the trait `for<'r> core::ops::Fn(&'r &'a T) -> bool` is not implemented for the type `for<'r> core::ops::Fn(&'r T) -> bool + 'a`
<anon>:5 fn filter_one<'a, T: Int>(input: &'a Vec<T>) -> Filter<&T, Iter<'a, T>, Fn(&T) -> bool>{
<anon>:6     input.iter().filter(|&x| x == Int::one())
<anon>:7 }
<anon>:5:1: 7:2 note: required by `core::iter::Filter`
<anon>:5 fn filter_one<'a, T: Int>(input: &'a Vec<T>) -> Filter<&T, Iter<'a, T>, Fn(&T) -> bool>{
<anon>:6     input.iter().filter(|&x| x == Int::one())
<anon>:7 }
error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
playpen: application terminated with error code 101
```

How do I tell `rustc` that `Fn(&T) -> bool` is `Sized?`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Correct way to return an Iterator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27535289/correct-way-to-return-an-iterator)

Comment: Probably yes, but the compiler doesn't guide me enough, I'll edit!

Comment: In that case, it may be a duplicate of [How to return a generic Map struct?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27496278/155423)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

## Rust 1.26

```
fn filter_one(input: &[u8]) -> impl Iterator<Item = &u8> {
    input.iter().filter(|&&x| x == 1)
}

fn main() {
    let nums = vec![1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3];
    let other: Vec<_> = filter_one(&nums).collect();
    println!("{:?}", other);
}
```

## Rust 1.0

```
fn filter_one<'a>(input: &'a [u8]) -> Box<Iterator<Item = &'a u8> + 'a> {
    Box::new(input.iter().filter(|&&x| x == 1))
}

fn main() {
    let nums = vec![1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3];
    let other: Vec<_> = filter_one(&nums).collect();
    println!("{:?}", other);
}
```

This solution requires additional allocation. We create a *boxed trait object*. Here, the size of the object is always known (it's just a pointer or two), but the size of the object in the heap does not need to be known.

As [Vladimir Matveev points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27648199/155423), if your predicate logic doesn't need any information from the environment, you can use a function instead of a closure:

```
use std::{iter::Filter, slice::Iter};

fn filter_one<'a>(input: &'a [u8]) -> Filter<Iter<u8>, fn(&&u8) -> bool> {
    fn is_one(a: &&u8) -> bool {
        **a == 1
    }

    input.iter().filter(is_one)
}

fn main() {
    let nums = vec![1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3];
    let other: Vec<_> = filter_one(&nums).collect();
    println!("{:?}", other);
}
```

See also:

- [What is the correct way to return an Iterator (or any other trait)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27535289/155423)

Comment: thank you!! I'll use this workaround for now until rust gains the ability to express generics as fn return types!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that an explicit implementation of closure traits on a structure is an overkill in this situation. Regular functions also implement all relevant traits, and you don't need to define a custom structure and implement these traits yourself. Moreover, this will break once you start using stable Rust versions (as they won't allow gated features, and custom implementation of unboxed closure traits will remain gated).

Comment: Of course, if you *do* need the closure to capture its environment, then this is the only option as of now...

Comment: What if the function inside `impl` or `trait` definition?

Comment: @DrSensor did you attempt either of these yourself? You can return an `impl Trait` just fine from inherent methods on a type. You [cannot use it with a trait](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39482131/155423) at all .

Comment: @Shepmaster Yes. I have a few problems returning `impl Iterator` from methods which at the end I use associated types instead of `impl Trait`.

Answer (score 15):

Unfortunately, it is impossible to return iterators which depend on closures (specifically closures, functions will work fine; see below), like the ones returned by `filter()` or `map()` adapters. Here's why.

This is the signature of `filter()` iterator extension method:

```
fn filter<P>(self, predicate: P) -> Filter<A, Self, P> where P: FnMut(&A) -> bool
```

Note that the closure argument accepts any type which implements [`FnMut`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnMut.html) trait. That's right, most if not all of the standard libraries have recently been switched to use unboxed closures instead of old boxed ones.

This signature means, however, that if you specify a *closure* as an argument to `filter()`, just like you do in `filter_one()`:

```
input.iter().filter(|&x| x == Int::one())
```

then after monomorphization of this particular call `P` will become *some anonymous unnamed type* generated by the compiler. Because it is unnamed, naturally, you can't specify it in type signatures, consequently, you also *cannot specify a type of an iterator which depends on unboxed closure* - you just wouldn't know what to write as the third argument to `Filter<A, I, P>`.

You can work around this by using a function instead of a closure, which should be sufficient for your use case:

```
use std::slice::Items;
use std::iter::Filter;
use std::num::Int;

fn filter_one<T: Int>(input: &[T]) -> Filter<&T, Items<T>, fn(&&T) -> bool> {
    fn equal_to_one<U: Int>(&&x: &&U) -> bool { x == Int::one() }
    input.iter().filter(equal_to_one::<T>)
}

fn main() {
    let v = [1i, 2, 3];
    let r: Vec<int> = filter_one(v.as_slice()).map(|x| *x).collect();
    println!("{}", r);
}
```

Note that I also have changed `&Vec<T>` to `&[T]` - you should never use `&Vec<T>` because it needlessly limits flexibility of your code.

For more general case of closures, however, it is impossible to do this without abstract return types. There is a proposal to add them, but it was postponed until after 1.0.

Comment: thank you very much for your detailed explanation, I understand the problem! :)

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Does a `Box<Iterator>` help in any way for this case? Or does that not help in the presence of a closure?

Comment: Yes, `Box<Iterator>` could also help. In fact, trait objects are currently *the* solution for the generic problem of returning closures. You can see how it can be done in Shepmaster's answer.