# How to set lifetime for boxed closure capturing `self`?

Tags: iterator, rust, lifetime

I want to return an iterator (in particular, a `Filter`).  I used a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27646925/how-do-i-return-a-filter-iterator-from-a-function) that suggests returning a boxed iterator.  The problem is that my filter captures `self` and I get:

> error: closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `self`, which is owned by the current function

But I think I'm being explicit that `self` has lifetime `'a` and so does the `Box` I'm returning:

```
fn occupied_iter_x<'a>(&'a self) -> Box<Iterator<Item=i32> + 'a> {
    Box::new( (0..32).filter( |&pos| match self.at(pos) { Occupied::Empty => false, _ => true } ) )
}
```

This is an attempt to simplify my first effort, where I created a new `FooIterator` which owns a reference to `self` in basically the same way.

If I use most of the same syntax to simply capture `self` as a member reference it works fine:

```
struct Foo { junk: i32 }
struct FooIterator<'a> { foo: &'a Foo }
impl Foo {
    fn foo<'a>(&'a self) -> Box<FooIterator<'a>> {
        Box::new( FooIterator { foo: self } )
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get an error because your closure receives a reference to `self`, which itself is a reference. However, since the reference points to a local variable, that reference becomes invalid as soon as the function returns.

To fix this, add the `move` keyword before the closure. This instructs the compiler to **move** the closed-over variables in the closure, rather than **pass a reference** to those variables to the closure.

```
fn occupied_iter_x<'a>(&'a self) -> Box<Iterator<Item=i32> + 'a> {
    Box::new( (0..32).filter(move |&pos| match self.at(pos) { Occupied::Empty => false, _ => true } ) )
}
```

Comment: So you're saying that the closure is implicitly capturing `&self`, which has its own lifetime independent of `'a`.  It's doing this because closures capture by reference?  But `self` is immutable (easily verified with a `self=self` test) so why wouldn't it just capture it by value?

Comment: @BenJackson, if you don't use `move` keyword, a closure will capture its environment by reference (in this case the environment would contain a reference to &self, that is, a double reference). If you do, it will capture it by value. That's just how closures in Rust work.