# Specify lifetime of a returned reference to a closure

Tags: rust, closures, lifetime

Given this struct:

```
struct Token<'a> {
     r: &'a Regex,
     f: &'a Fn(String) -> Symbol
}
```

I can't figure out the right syntax to specify the closure lifetime when returning it from a fn:

```
fn get_tokens<'a>() -> Vec<Token<'a>> {
    static ref NUMBER: Regex = Regex::new(r"$(\d+|\d*\.\d+)").unwrap(); // TODO avoid "000"?
    let num_token = Token{ r: &*NUMBER, f: &|s| Symbol::Number(s) };
    let tokens = vec![num_token];

    tokens
}
```

Without a lifetime parameter, I get the error that the borrowed value doesn't life long enough:

```
error: borrowed value does not live long enough
   --> src\syntax\lex.rs:49:45
   |
49 |     let num_token = Token{ r: &*NUMBER, f: &|s| Symbol::Number(s) };
   |                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ temporary value created here
...
53 | }
   | - temporary value only lives until here
   |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the block at 36:38...
     --> src\syntax\lex.rs:36:39
   |
36 | fn get_tokens<'a>() -> Vec<Token<'a>> {
   |                                       ^
```

And I can't find any examples that show specifying a lifetime parameter for a closure like this.

Comment: Nothing special about a closure here. You cannot return a reference to a value that was allocated inside a function.

Comment: You'll likely be interested in http://stackoverflow.com/q/27535289/155423 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/27646925/155423.