# "wrong number of type arguments" when implementing IntoIterator that returns HashMap::IntoIter

Tags: rust, hashmap, iterator

I have the following code:

```
use std::{collections::HashMap, hash::Hash, rc::Rc};

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct LFUCache<K: Hash + Eq, V> {
    values: HashMap<Rc<K>, ValueCounter<V>>,
    capacity: usize,
    min_frequency: usize,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct ValueCounter<V> {
    value: V,
    count: usize,
}

impl<K: Hash + Eq, V> IntoIterator for LFUCache<K, V> {
    type Item = (Rc<K>, V);
    type IntoIter = std::collections::HashMap::IntoIter<Rc<K>, V>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        return self
            .values
            .into_iter()
            .map(|(key, valueCounter)| (key, valueCounter.value));
    }
}
```

It throws an error saying:

```
error[E0107]: wrong number of type arguments: expected at least 2, found 0
  --> src/lib.rs:18:21
   |
18 |     type IntoIter = std::collections::HashMap::IntoIter<Rc<K>, V>;
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected at least 2 type arguments
```

I've looked into the docs and my use-case seems pretty analogous [to the example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.24.0/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html).

How do I fix this?

Comment: By the way, idiomatic Rust uses `snake_case` for variables, methods, macros, fields and modules; `UpperCamelCase` for types and enum variants; and `SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE` for statics and constants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`HashMap::IntoIter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.43.0/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#impl-IntoIterator-2), the associated type from the [`IntoIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.43.0/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html) trait, does not have any type parameters. `HashMap` *does*: `HashMap::<Rc<K>, V>::IntoIter`. That's ambiguous, so you have to fully qualify it:

```
type IntoIter = <std::collections::HashMap::<Rc<K>, V> as IntoIterator>::IntoIter;
```

This is usually expressed as

```
type IntoIter = std::collections::hash_map::IntoIter<Rc<K>, V>;
```

Then you run into the problem that you are attempting to lie to the compiler, as you *aren't returning that type*:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:21:9
   |
21 | /         self.values
22 | |             .into_iter()
23 | |             .map(|(key, valueCounter)| (key, valueCounter.value))
   | |_________________________________________________________________^ expected struct `std::collections::hash_map::IntoIter`, found struct `std::iter::Map`
   |
   = note: expected struct `std::collections::hash_map::IntoIter<_, V>`
              found struct `std::iter::Map<std::collections::hash_map::IntoIter<_, ValueCounter<V>>, [closure@src/lib.rs:23:18: 23:65]>`
```

Following the hints from the linked questions, you end up with

```
use std::{collections::hash_map::IntoIter, iter::Map};

impl<K: Hash + Eq, V> IntoIterator for LFUCache<K, V> {
    type Item = (Rc<K>, V);
    type IntoIter =
        Map<IntoIter<Rc<K>, ValueCounter<V>>, fn((Rc<K>, ValueCounter<V>)) -> (Rc<K>, V)>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        fn xform<K, V>((key, vc): (Rc<K>, ValueCounter<V>)) -> (Rc<K>, V) {
            (key, vc.value)
        }

        self.values.into_iter().map(xform)
    }
}
```

See also:

- [How do I return a Filter iterator from a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27646925/155423)
- [What is the correct way to return an Iterator (or any other trait)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27535289/155423)