# How to return Map iterator

Tags: rust

I'd like to write a function that returns the lazy iterator resulting from a `map()`:

```
fn mapper(v: Vec<u8>) -> ??? {
  v.iter().map(|x| x + 1)
}
```

I've used `core::iter::Map<core::slice::Iter<'a, u8>, FnOnce(&u8) -> u8>` for ??? and I get errors like: `map.rs:3:1: 5:2 error: the trait core::marker::Sized is not implemented for the type for<'r> core::ops::FnOnce(&'r u8) -> u8 [E0277]`, for example.  I also get various issues relating to the closure and I'm confused about whether returning a closure is even possible.

(I definitely want the return type to be a lazy iterator, not a `Vec<_>` resulting from a `collect()`.  My actual code does something more complicated in the map.)

It looks like we are limited by the same issues described here:  [How do I return a Filter iterator from a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27646925/how-do-i-return-a-filter-iterator-from-a-function)

Comment: Why is this *not* a duplicate of the question you linked to?

Comment: Or of the other two it links to: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27535289/155423 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/27496278/155423 ?

Comment: I'm happy making this a duplicate.  My case had  to do with `map()` and the question regarding `filter()` never  came up in any searches.  Only after I thought to search for filter did I find the  other question, so I figured a duplicate with a pointer would help others.

Comment: You can mark it as a duplicate yourself — I'd pick whichever was most useful to solving your problem. Duplicates are great - they are nice signposts for future searchers!